# Can you use HDMI output from a PC to TV and then RCA output from TV to a stereo receiver?

Tags: audio

I have my PC hooked up to my LCD TV using HDMI output, but I am trying to hook it up to my old stereo receiver which only has RCA inputs.

I have attempted to use the RCA Audio Out from the TV to the receiver, which works for normal TV, but it doesn't when I switch to the PC. No sound at all.

Why is this and can I do anything about it other than buying some sort of converter or upgrading to a new receiver?

Comment: Your graphics card probably won't transmit sound over HDMI. The easiest way is to buy a normal headphone jack to RCA converter and plug that into your PC, going straight to the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

How about, assuming you have a fairly modern receiver, just running the hdmi to the receiver first (as pass through)  and then another hdmi to the tv??  I haven't done this myself, but it is how I understand it to work....

Answer (score 0):

I have roughly the same setup.

I bought two HDMI cables, very cheap from ebay and then connected my ATI 5850 to my receivers HDMI IN and then my receivers HDMI OUT to the TV. That way it supports all the latest HD Audio Streams, DTS-HD, TRUE-HD to name a couple.

Make sure you have a Graphics card that supports bitstreaming or it's not worth it then. All ATI 5000/6000 series cards support bitstreaming, I haven't actually checked the Nvidia ones.